# jqTransform clone select field

Tags: jquery, jqtransform

using iqTransform, I've code

```
function mlAddVal (btn)
{
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var name = btn.name.substr(7);
        var tr = btn;
        while (tr.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'tr') {
            tr = tr.parentNode;
        }
        var tr_new = tr.parentNode.insertBefore(tr.cloneNode(true),tr.nextSibling);

        mlCheckForLast(name);
    }

}
```

But when new select field was added, jqTransform doesn't work with him...

I try to do reinit jqTransform

```
$(".custom_form").jqTransform({imgPath:'/media/js/jqtransformplugin/img'});
```

But it didn't help.